# react native PanGestureHandler Does not work

Tags: react-native

I am newbie in react native and I am trying to use the panGestureHandler  , guided by the documentation the code was written as follow:

```
    import { GestureHandlerRootView,PanGestureHandler } from "react-native-gesture- 
    handler";
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import { Animated,Button,Dimensions,StyleSheet,ScrollView ,View,Text} from "react- 
    native";
    import { useAnimatedGestureHandler, useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withSpring, 
    withTiming } from "react-native-reanimated";

 
    export default function App () {

    const progress= useSharedValue(2)
 
    const panHandler=useAnimatedGestureHandler({
      onStart:(event,context)=>{},
      onActive:(event,context)=>{},
      onEnd:(event,context)=>{}
   
    })

    const animatedStyle=useAnimatedStyle(()=>{
        return{
         borderRadius:progress.value*30
      }
    })

    return(
    <GestureHandlerRootView >
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={panHandler}>
       <Animated.View style={[styles.container,animatedStyle]}><Text>test</Text> 
       </Animated.View>
     </PanGestureHandler>
    </GestureHandlerRootView> 
     )}
```

but I always get the following error:

```
ERROR  Error: Expected `onGestureHandlerEvent` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.
```

Comment: what version you are using of react-native-gesture-handler ?.

Comment: the react-native-gesture-handler :~2.8.0

Answer (score 1):

import **Animated** from react-native-reanimated will fix this issue.

```
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  withSpring,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
```

Comment: appreciate your kind help